How can I show statistically that one of my replicates is likely contaminated?
I have a dataset that looks like the below: five replicate samples, each of which is composed of 4 different fractions that sum to 100%. The fifth sample clearly looks visually distinct from the other 4 but I don't know how to go about showing this statistically. It feels similar to a chi-squared test but those can't be used on percentages/proportions. My eventual goal is to justify the removal of this sample from the pooling of replicates that we do downstream since it seems likely that some other process was at work here instead of just the sampling variation. If the replicate is bad then I don't want to include it in the rest of the analysis.
v <- matrix(runif(20), ncol = 5)+c(1,6,2,0)
v <- sweep(v, MARGIN = 2, STATS = c(5, 10, 7, 2, 3), `+`)
v[4, 5] <- 20
v[2, 5] <- 100
v <- sweep(v, MARGIN = 2, STATS = colSums(v), `/`)

barplot(v, names.arg = LETTERS[1:5])



There's no general statistical method or principle that would "show this statistically:" you need to apply your knowledge of the data generation process, along with your analytical objectives, to evaluate this situation.  A cautious analyst might perform their work on the original dataset and the "cleaned data" and report both sets of results.

@whuber Can I use statistics to calculate the likelihood that replicate E was produced by the same process that produced samples A through D? Kinda like a chi-squared analysis can calculate the likelihood that two sets of count data were produced from the same underlying population?

Statistics offers principles to reason from assumptions to conclusions.  To achieve anything with this dataset, you will need to make strong explicit assumptions.

I personally do not think that there is such a thing as an "outlier"; there is either erroneous data (measurement error, transcription error, etc.), or then there is data. It may be unexpected, it may look "out of place", but it is data.
As a general rule, experimenters and statisticians recommend to not remove outliers. See e.g. here or here on CV. I particularly like this quote from Andrew Gelman:

Stepwise regression is one of these things, like outlier detection and pie charts, which appear to be popular among non-statisticans but are considered by statisticians to be a bit of a joke.

Reference for the quote here. So, the general consensus is do not.
Now, if you have strong evidence of an error, not only can you, but you should remove this erroneous data. E.g., say that I am measuring shaft lengths on a production line; the length should 110mm, +/- 1mm; I measure 109.3, 110.1, 110.9, etc. Even 108.5 and 111.2, which both are out of specification; I keep them. Then one data point shows up as 190.5. Because I know the data generating process behind the measurements, I know this 190mm is simply impossible; we would never machine such a shaft, almost twice as long as it should be. It is most likely a transcription error (109.5; transposing digits is more common than one thinks), and I can either replace it by 190.5, or better yet, simply eliminate it.
Now, in your example, you provide no evidence of any error of any type. The only "flaw" is that this replicate does not look like the others. So what?  Note that, unless they are erroneous, "outliers" provide information about your data generating process. If you eliminate them, you will bias your answer towards a pre-conceived conclusion.
Note that some may suggest to do the analysis both with, and w/o the "outliers". But I do not find this helps; either the conclusions are the same with or w/o, then just include it from the beginning and do not even address the issue of "outliers". Or it gives you different answers; then which one do you believe? Both?
TL;DR; unless you have strong, defensible reasons to suspect a data error, do not remove "outliers". Not "looking like the other data" is not such a strong, defensible reason.

Understandable, but in this case I do believe the fifth sample to have been contaminated.   I've edited the question to reflect this.

"it seems likely that some other process was at work here instead of just the sampling variation" is not strong evidence of erroneous data collection. How was the data collected, how could errors have occured, what kind of error, etc.? Can you "sell" the story that an error occured, and will your audience buy it? Based on what you provided so far, I know I would not buy...

It sounds like you're curious about the same question I am - how "anomalous" does a sample need to look before we can assume the influence of additional processes? The example you offer has a simple statistical test for outlier membership (a t-test). If I had a thousand replicates that all looked like my first 4 and the fifth still appeared anomalous, would that be a persuasive story? There should be an equivalent to the chi-squared test that works on proportions and that's what I'm interested in.

A t-test will NEVER detect outliers. No matter how many sd's the datapoint is away, such values are plausible (a normal distribution can take arbirtrarily large values). Please read the linked CV posts; unless you can demonstrate that there was an error (measurement, transcription, etc.), you should not exclude data just because "it is anomalous". Data is data (unless it is error). That would basically be cheating; only consider the data which suits me...

Perhaps our fields are sufficiently different to allow alternative explanations, but in my experience contamination resulting from the sampling method is considered erroneous and should not be included. Thus the desire to identify such problems with confidence. Your illustration of shaft lengths above provides a lovely example of exactly how an "anomalous" measurement can identify that something has gone wrong and, per your recommendation, be eliminated.
